# Varchar[HH:MM] SUM in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagridview with cells that contains varchar values with HH:mm format, when I need to do a sum of these values I use the function

```
private void CalcTime
{
    string span = dataGridView1.Columns["Horas"].ToString();
    double seconds = 0;
    seconds = dataGridView1.Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse((x.Cells["Horas"].Value.ToString())).TotalSeconds);
    string somat = "";
    double segundosc = seconds;
    somat = string.Format(
        "{0:00}:{1:00}", 
        segundosc / 3600, 
        (segundosc / 60) % 60, 
        segundosc % 60);
}
```

If the values are like 01:00 or 03:00 it's all right but if I had values like 01:30 the sum doesn't work. As below:[image]

How can I make it work right? 
Regards

Comment: @GrantWinney I was able to replicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the sum of the seconds will be 20400 and when you divide that by 3600 you'll get 5.666666. And because your variable is a `double` and you are using the format `{0:00}`, the value will get rounded.  You either need to cast the sum to `int` or use `Math.Floor`.

```
int seconds = (int)dataGridView1.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse((x.Cells["Horas"].Value.ToString())).TotalSeconds);
```

OR

```
somat = string.Format(
    "{0:00}:{1:00}", 
    Math.Floor(segundosc / 3600), 
    (segundosc / 60) % 60);
```

Also you don't need the last  parameter in your `string.Format`.

Another option is to convert back to `TimeSpan` with `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`.

```
double seconds = dataGridView1.Rows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse((x.Cells["Horas"].Value.ToString())).TotalSeconds);
TimeSpan totalTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
string somat = totalTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `TimeSpan.Add` method without converting to seconds and back to `TimeSpan` type

```
TimeSpan all = New TimeSpan(0);
foreach( DataGridViewRow dgvr In dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    all = all.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(dgvr.Cells["Horas"].Value.ToString()));
}
string somat = all.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

Comment: It's too bad there isn't a `Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable<TimeSpan>)`.  But you could do this with `Enumerable.Aggregate`.

Comment: @juharr, sorry, don't understand why I need `Enumerable.Sum()` here?

Comment: You could replace the `foreach` with `Enumerable.Agregate` to sum the values.  I was just saying that it's too bad there isn't a way to use `Enumerable.Sum` with `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @juharr, On my opinion in this case `foreach` is faster and simpler(readable) then extension method `Sum` or `Aggregate`. `Foreach` looping the `datagridviewrow` collection without converting to `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>`. I like `LINQ` too, but in this case it seems overkill